# How to read a subsection from a firebase database

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this code to access a Firebase Database, but I am cannot figure out how to read the sub array of strings. (the JSON structure is below)).  The code I have returns the top level items, but not the list of strings.  Would someone be able to assist with this issue?

Here is my function to read from the DB:

```
func sizes(userId: String = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, success: @escaping ([Sizes]) -> ()) {
        let ref = Router.sizes.reference()
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name")   //userId)
        query.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            var array = [Sizes]()
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let size = Mapper<Sizes>().map(JSON: (child as! DataSnapshot).value as! [String : AnyObject]) {
                    array.append(size)
                }
            }
            success(array)
        })
    }
```

My Firebase JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "-SzCat_001": {
   "name": "Womans",
    "sizeCategories": {
      "name": "Pants",
      "sizeDescriptor": [
        "00",
        "0",
        "2",
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "10",
        "12",
        "XL"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what I get returned?

> [0] = {
>       name = "Womans"
>       sizeCategories = 0 values {}   }

I am trying to figure out how to read the sizeCategories list of strings as a subarray of sizes.

Here is my definition of sizes and sizeCategories:

```
struct Sizes: Mappable {

    var name: String = ""
    var sizeCategories = [SizeCategories]()

    init() {
    }

    init?(map: Map) {
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        sizeCategories <- map["sizeCategories"]
    }
}

struct SizeCategories: Mappable {

    var name: String = ""
    var sizeDescriptor = [String]()

    init() {
    }

    init?(map: Map) {
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        sizeDescriptor <- map["sizeDescriptor"]
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're jumping through a lot of hoops to read the data here. You could just `let allMyData = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]` and know that each internal value is also a `[String: AnyObject]`. But if you really want to destructure into something more typed with this mapping technique, have a look at your `sizes` definition:

```
var sizeCategories = [SizeCategories]()
```

This says "sizeCategories is an array of SizeCategories type". But your data is not structured as an array, it is a dict:

```
"sizeCategories": {
  "name": "Pants",
  "sizeDescriptor": [
    "00",
    "0",
    "2",
    "4",
    "6",
    "8",
    "10",
    "12",
    "XL"
  ]
}
```

You need to adjust your definition and mapping method here for this field.